# How do i handle Remote Method calls via AsyncToken?

Tags: apache-flex, remoteobject, asynctoken

So here is the mxml i would like to get working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import argoseye.main.Golem;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.rpc.Responder;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.InvokeEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("destination");
                ro.endpoint = "http://Jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";
                ro.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,onInvoke);

                var token:AsyncToken = new AsyncToken();
                token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult,onFault));

                token = ro.getCells();
                textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Clickhandler called .... \n";

            }

            public function onResult(event:ResultEvent,token:Object):void {
                textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Resulthandler called .... \n";
                var cellList:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;

            }

            public function onFault(event:FaultEvent,token:Object):void
            {
                textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Faulthandler called .... \n";
            }

            public function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
                textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Invokehandler called .... \n";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button x="1093" y="575" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    <s:TextArea x="1022" y="183" id="textfeld"/>
</s:Application>
```

The output is

> Invokehandler called ....
>
> Clickhandler called ....

The Resulthandler doesnt get called,  allthough the BlazeDS Console registers an successfull Resultevent. What do I do wrong?

Edit: I tried exporting the procedure into a class, which is supposed to manage these things.

```
package argoseye.main
```

{
    import flash.events.Event;

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.messaging.ChannelSet;
import mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel;
import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

public class Schem
{
    public var info:String="";


    public function Schem()
    {       
    }

    public function loadCurrentSchem():void
    {
        var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("Hibernatetest");
        ro.endpoint = "http://jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";

        var token:AsyncToken = ro.getCells();
        token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult,onFault));

        info = info + "Loader Called ...";


    }

    public function onResult(event:ResultEvent,token:Object):void {
        var cellList:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;
        info = info + "Resulthandler Called";

    }

    public function onFault(event:FaultEvent,token:Object):void
    {

    }
    //Eventhandlers


    //Getters, Setters


}
```

}

If i call it, it doesnt reach the eventhandler. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error lies in these lines:

```
var token:AsyncToken = new AsyncToken();
token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult,onFault));
token = ro.getCells();
```

You're creating a new token on line 1.
You assign a responder on line 2.
And then you reassign the token on line 3.

What you do on line 3 is effectively creating a new token, thus it doesn't have the responder attached to it, because it's a new instance.

So it should be:

```
var token:AsyncToken = ro.getCells(); 
//ro.getCells() will return a new instance of AsyncToken
token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult,onFault));
```

Comment: Very enlightening! Thank you. I wasnt very clear about the deeper meaning of `token = ro.getCells();`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import argoseye.main.Golem;

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
        import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
        import mx.rpc.Responder;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.InvokeEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var ro:RemoteObject = new RemoteObject("destination");
            ro.endpoint = "http://Jesus/blazeds/messagebroker/amf";
            ro.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE,onInvoke);

            var token:AsyncToken = ro.getCells();
            token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult,onFault));
            textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Clickhandler called .... \n";

        }

        public function onResult(event:ResultEvent,token:Object):void {
            textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Resulthandler called .... \n";
            var cellList:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;

        }

        public function onFault(event:FaultEvent,token:Object):void
        {
            textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Faulthandler called .... \n";
        }

        public function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
            textfeld.text = textfeld.text + "Invokehandler called .... \n";
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button x="1093" y="575" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
<s:TextArea x="1022" y="183" id="textfeld"/>
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the AsyncToken returned by the ro.getCells() function is a totally different one from the AsyncToken object that you created by new. So the event listeners are not added to the token, and you don't get the right behavior.